# Retrieve multiple Parse Images(Swift)

Tags: ios, database, swift, parse-platform

Below is an example of how i would typically retrieve images from my Parse.com. I have now run into the situation where i would like to retrieve 20+ images from Parse but i am looking for a more efficient way to do so. Please can someone explain how to implement this in code and how i should store the 20+ PFFiles in Parse?

```
func loadData(){
let findDataParse = PFQuery(className: "JobListing")
findDataParse.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
        for object in objects! {
           let userImageFile = object["ImageOne"] as! PFFile
            let userImageFile1 = object["ImageTwo"] as! PFFile
            let userImageFile2 = object["ImageThree"] as! PFFile
            userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                let listingImage1 = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                userImageFile1.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData1: NSData?, error1: NSError?) -> Void in
                    let listingImage2 = UIImage(data:imageData1!)
                    userImageFile2.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData2: NSData?, error1: NSError?) -> Void in
                        let listingImage3 = UIImage(data:imageData2!)

self.flyerImageLarge1.image = listingImage1
self.flyerImageLarge2.image = listingImage2
self.flyerImageLarge3.image = listingImage3
}}}}}}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ParseUI for cleaner and more efficient code.
To do so, add the ParseUI framework.
Then, click the image and change the "class" to PFImageView.
[You can see this here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gG1o.png)

Once you do that, you can easily set the PFImageView's image:

```
if let myServerImage = object.valueForKey("imageFromUser") as? PFFile {
        self.myImage.file = myServerImage
        self.myImage.loadInBackground()
    }
```

Where myServerImage is the image you are retrieving from the Parse server and myImage is the image in your storyboard.

In your case it will be something like this:

```
func loadData(){
    let findDataParse = PFQuery(className: "JobListing")
    findDataParse.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
        if let myServerImage = object.valueForKey("ImageOne") as? PFFile {
            self.flyerImageLarge1.file = myServerImage
            self.flyerImageLarge1.loadInBackground()
        }
    if let myServerImage = object.valueForKey("ImageTwo") as? PFFile {
            self.flyerImageLarge2.file = myServerImage
            self.flyerImageLarge2.loadInBackground()
        }
    if let myServerImage = object.valueForKey("ImageThree") as? PFFile {
            self.flyerImageLarge3.file = myServerImage
            self.flyerImageLarge3.loadInBackground()
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend adding the if let statement so that you don't get an error when an image doesn't exist.

Comment: Would you recommend me doing this for 20+ images from parse?

Answer (score 0):

*Please forgive me if what I am saying is obvious or already considered. I'm not completely familiar with what you are doing, but it looks applicable.*

**Assuming you are not using it already, you will need to use a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Basically, a function that calls itself until the end condition.**

I'm not familiar with your code so I'll demonstrate with a simple example in JavaScript:

```
/* A "public" function that your program will call */
function getStuff(total)
{
    //quick positive check
    if (total > 0)
    {
        //start and pass in an empty array
        return _getStuffRecursion(total, []);
    }
    else
    {
        //total is not positive, return empty array
        return [];
    }
}

/* A "private" function that will do the recursion */
function _getStuffRecursion(total, resultsArray)
{
    //do work this is where you would call your function that does the work.
    var someResource = Math.random();

    //add work to the array collected so far
    resultsArray.push(someResource);

    //change count
    var newTotal = total - 1;

    //check condition
    if (newTotal > 0)
    {
        //recursive condition, go to the next level down and pass in what is collected so far
        return _getStuffRecursion(newTotal, resultsArray)
    }
    else
    {
        //end condition met, just return the array with everything collected from the upper levels
        return resultsArray;
    }
}

/* Start */

//get started by calling the "public" function
var results = getStuff(20);

//print it to console
console.log(results);
```

If this solution works, I'm sure you can adapt it to Parse.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this applies. Excuse me for not understanding. Do you mind explaining further?

Comment: A recursive function is useful when subsequent actions depend on the actions prior to it. Does your code require that? If not, maybe a simple "for loop" will do the trick.